# How to fillna() slice of dataset with mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, fillna

Please help me understand why this syntax is not working

`data[data.country == 'SA'].postal_code.fillna(data[data.country == 'SA'].postal_code.mode(), inplace=True)`

Basically what I want to do is `fillna()` the `postal_code` column with the most frequent postal code where the country is equivalent to SA. When I run the above code I don't get an error, however when I run `data[data.postal_code.isnull()]` I still get `NaN`'s in the postal code column where country == 'SA'

Comment: Because the inplace operation was done on a sliced copy. Try `data.update(data[data.country == 'SA'].postal_code.fillna(data[data.country == 'SA'].postal_code.mode())`?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also doesn't return an error but the postal code column still has `NaN`'s in it